# Write to file within WebAssembly

Tags: javascript, webassembly, wasm-bindgen

I have the following piece of `C` code which is on the hook to be compiled into `WebAssembly`.

```
# include <stdio.h>

int main() {

FILE *f = fopen("file.txt", "w");
if (f == NULL)
{
            printf("Error opening file!\n");
            return 0;
}

/* print some text */
const char *text = "Write this to the file";
fprintf(f, "Some text: %s\n", text);

/* print integers and floats */
int i = 1;
float py = 3.1415927;
fprintf(f, "Integer: %d, float: %f\n", i, py);

char c = 'A';
fprintf(f, "A character: %c\n", c);

fclose(f);

return 0;

}
```

So I use the following commands to generate a `wasm` file and corresponding `js` file:

```
emcc write.c -s WASM=1 -o write.html
```

However, when I tried to use a JS engine (like `v8`) to execute this piece of code, I simply cannot find the produced the output. Nor do I received any error:

```
➜  test_code ~/v8/v8/out/x64.release/d8 write.js
➜  test_code
```

So according to my understanding, `wasm` code needs to leverages `JS` to use some system-related functionalities, like the I/O related operators. And perhaps it may be not allowed to "manipulate" the file system within this browser environment? Because in general what happens inside a browser, it should stay within the browser.

So I am writing to inquire the best practice to migrate file I/O related C program onto the `WebAssembly` environment. Any comment will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`d8` does have a `write` function ([v8/src/d8.cc?l=1706](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/v8/src/d8.cc?l=1706)) for I/O write, but Emscripten's [`shell.js`](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/blob/incoming/src/shell.js) never uses it for simple JS shells. You will need some hacking in Emscripten's code if you want it to work in simple JS shells. Try exploring [`emscripten/src/library_fs.js`](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/blob/incoming/src/library_fs.js).

EDIT: Just realized that d8's `write` function only [print to `stdout`](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/v8/src/d8.cc?l=1252), so it is not what you want. Looks like writing to file from simple JS shells are not possible (they are only for JS engine developers to test stuffs anyway).

I didn't verify this, but I think I/O write will probably work out of the box when running the test code in Node.js.

Follow-up questions:

Emscripten generates the JS wrapper code by pre-processing and concatenating `shell.js`, `preamble.js`, `postamble.js` and some code generated at compile-time from [`emscripten.py`](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/blob/incoming/emscripten.py) and [`compiler.js`](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/blob/incoming/src/compiler.js). The pre-processing of JS code uses C-style preprocessor (`#if`, `#else`) plus some `{{{ }}}`, which is why the Emscripten's JS code looks very funny.

Many C functions are implemented in C and JS *together*. C-part of it is linked into WebAssembly directly (see their implementation [here](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/tree/incoming/system/lib)), JS-part of it are implemented in `library_*.js` under [here](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/tree/incoming/src).

Currently, Chrome is the only browser that has a [Web FileSystem API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystem). Google and Mozilla is currently working on standardizing [Writable Files API](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/11/writable-files). The first reaction most people have will be "this is a bad idea", but since browsers already allow executing untrusted code in user system (in a sandbox), writing files is probably not the most dangerous thing browser can do (https://twitter.com/ericlaw/status/1066149633855053825).

Comment: Thanks for your answer John, it helps a lot. So just two follow-up questions, is the `shell.js` being used to produce JS code like the `write.js` `emcc` produced? Also, let's suppose in the browser I somehow enabled the functionality to write/read the file system. Woudn't that cause some serious security problems? I know that `WebAssembly` has a sandbox facility, but as long as the file system APIs are enabled, it do becomes a security risk in any sense. Does this make sense to you? Or am I missed anything here?

Comment: Edited my answers directly since it is quite long.

Comment: WASM is intendet to work not only on browsers. When it is not on a browser there is no restriction on library on reading and writing.